# Organize HTML Table (with jQuery?)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax, sharepoint

I have a searchable HTML table, that retrieves SharePoint list items from a multiple subsites, and everything about it is nearly perfect. The one issue I am facing is that the "Program" item keeps printing every time the function runs through/loops, but I only want it to print the "Program" header/item once, and have the correlating items all print under the one Program header. I will attach below a screenshot of my table and how it prints, as well as my function that reads the information and prints it to the table. Any suggestions/help/advice would be greatly appreciated.

Would I use something along the lines of an if statement?

For example, have the Meeting Minutes and MSR rows for each type of Program print under only one Program.

**Actual Result:**
[image: Printed Table]

```
**Expected Result** 
    +------------+----------------------+-----------+------------+--------------+--------------+
    | Program    | To                   |  Date     |   Approved | Notes        | Deliverable  |
    +------------+----------------------+-----------+------------+--------------+--------------+
    | Program 1  | example@example.com  | 12/23/2018| Yes        | Example Notes| MSR          |
    |            | example@example.com  | 03/30/2020| Yes        | Example Notes| Meeting Mins |
    +------------+----------------------+-----------+------------+--------------+--------------+
    | Program 2  | example@example.com  | 12/23/2018| Yes        | Example Notes| MSR          |
    |            | example@example.com  | 12/03/2017| Yes        | Example Notes| Meeting Mins |
    +------------+----------------------+-----------+------------+--------------+--------------+
    | Program 3  | example@example.com  | 04/17/2020| Yes        | Example Notes| MSR          |
    |            | example@example.com  | 03/30/2020| No         | Example Notes| Meeting Mins |
    +------------+----------------------+-----------+------------+--------------+--------------+
```

Here is my code:

```
    .then(([r1, r2, r3]) => {
  const objItems = r1.concat(r2,r3);
  console.log(objItems);
  var tableContent =
    '<table id="deliverablesTable" style="width:100%" border="1 px"><thead><tr><td><strong>Program</strong></td>' +
    "<td><strong>To</strong></td>" +
    "<td><strong>Date Submitted</strong></td>" +
    "<td><strong>Approved</strong></td>" +
    "<td><strong>Notes</strong></td>" +
    "<td><strong>Deliverable</strong></td>" +
    "</tr></thead><tbody>";

  for (var i = 0; i < objItems.length; i++) {
        if (objItems.Program == "1"){
            tableContent += "<tr>";
            tableContent += "<td>" + objItems[i].Program + "</td>";
            tableContent += "</tr>";
            tableContent += "<tr>";
            tableContent += "<td> </td>";
            tableContent += "<td>" + objItems[i].To + "</td>";
            tableContent += "<td>" + objItems[i].Date + "</td>";
            tableContent += "<td>" + objItems[i].Approved + "</td>";
            tableContent += "<td>" + objItems[i].Notes + "</td>";
            tableContent += "<td>" + objItems[i].Deliverable + "</td>";
            tableContent += "</tr>";
        }
        else if (objItems.Program == "2"){
            tableContent += "<tr>";
            tableContent += "<td>" + objItems[i].Program + "</td>";
            tableContent += "</tr>";
            tableContent += "<tr>";
            tableContent += "<td> </td>";
            tableContent += "<td>" + objItems[i].To + "</td>";
            tableContent += "<td>" + objItems[i].Date + "</td>";
            tableContent += "<td>" + objItems[i].Approved + "</td>";
            tableContent += "<td>" + objItems[i].Notes + "</td>";
            tableContent += "<td>" + objItems[i].Deliverable + "</td>";
            tableContent += "</tr>";
        }   
        else if (objItems.Program == "3"){
            tableContent += "<tr>";
            tableContent += "<td>" + objItems[i].Program + "</td>";
            tableContent += "</tr>";
            tableContent += "<tr>";
            tableContent += "<td> </td>";
            tableContent += "<td>" + objItems[i].To + "</td>";
            tableContent += "<td>" + objItems[i].Date + "</td>";
            tableContent += "<td>" + objItems[i].Approved + "</td>";
            tableContent += "<td>" + objItems[i].Notes + "</td>";
            tableContent += "<td>" + objItems[i].Deliverable + "</td>";
            tableContent += "</tr>";
        }
  }
  $("#deliverables").append(tableContent);
})
.catch((err) => {
  alert("Error: " + err);
  console.error(err);
});
```

});
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ULOMF.png

Comment: Assuming the first `td` should always cover two rows, just add `rowspan="2"` to it, as an attribute, and don't output the `td` at all when `i` is an even number

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan the <td> for Program 1? IF that is what you are talking about there are going to be more than just the two which are under it, not sure how many to be exact. Is there a way to set the rowspan to a count?

Comment: Yes, absolutely, but you need to determine exactly how many rows have the same value in the `Program` property and then set the value to that number.

Comment: I am still a bit confused by your response, but understand it at the same time if that makes sense. Haha. Could you please edit into the code what you mean?

Comment: When I add the rowspan to(tableContent += "<td rowspan="2">" + objItems[i].Program + "</td>";) and update the script on my web part page. Now it will not print the table at all

Answer (score 1):

```js
var tableData =
[{'program': 'Program 1', 'To': 'example1', Date: '8/5', Approved: 'Yes', Notes: 'Note', Deliverable: 'Deliverable'},
{'program': 'Program 1', 'To': 'example2', Date: '8/5', Approved: 'Yes', Notes: 'Note', Deliverable: 'Deliverable'},
{'program': 'Program 2', 'To': 'example3', Date: '8/5', Approved: 'No', Notes: 'Note', Deliverable: 'Deliverable'},
{'program': 'Program 3', 'To': 'example4', Date: '8/5', Approved: 'Yes', Notes: 'Note', Deliverable: 'Deliverable'},
{'program': 'Program 3', 'To': 'example4', Date: '8/5', Approved: 'Yes', Notes: 'Note', Deliverable: 'Deliverable'},
{'program': 'Program 3', 'To': 'example4', Date: '8/5', Approved: 'Yes', Notes: 'Note', Deliverable: 'Deliverable'}]

//Fake loadData(...)
Promise.all(tableData)
.then((r1) => {
  const objItems = r1;
  makeTable(objItems);
})


function makeTable(tableData){
var group = {};
for(var d of tableData){
 if(group[d.program]){
    group[d.program].push(d);
 } else {
  group[d.program] = [d];
 }
}

var tableContent = ''; // I put the table in the html but you can populate it here

for (var prop in group) {
  tableContent += "<tr>";
  tableContent += "<td rowspan=\""+ group[prop].length +"\">" + prop + "</td>";
  tableContent += "<td>" + group[prop][0].To + "</td>";
  tableContent += "<td>" + group[prop][0].Date + "</td>";
  tableContent += "<td>" + group[prop][0].Approved + "</td>";
  tableContent += "<td>" + group[prop][0].Notes + "</td>";
  tableContent += "<td>" + group[prop][0].Deliverable + "</td>";
  tableContent += "</tr>";
  for(var i = 0; i < group[prop].length - 1; i++){
    tableContent += "<tr>";
    tableContent += "<td>" + group[prop][i+1].To + "</td>";
    tableContent += "<td>" + group[prop][i+1].Date + "</td>";
    tableContent += "<td>" + group[prop][i+1].Approved + "</td>";
    tableContent += "<td>" + group[prop][i+1].Notes + "</td>";
    tableContent += "<td>" + group[prop][i+1].Deliverable + "</td>";
    tableContent += "</tr>";
 }
}
$("#deliverablesTable").append(tableContent);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="deliverablesTable" style="width:100%" border="1 px">
<thead>
<tr>
 <td><strong>Program</strong></td>
 <td><strong>To</strong></td>
 <td><strong>Date</strong></td>
 <td><strong>Approved</strong></td>
 <td><strong>Notes</strong></td>
 <td><strong>Deliverable</strong></td>
</tr></thead><tbody>
```

Comment: So this is something along the lines of what I am seeking to do, but the array you created is static. I am using a promise callback function to pull data so I am not hard coding everything into one array. I will add the function to my code for example. Is there a way around that?

Comment: @zgoforth My answer is more of a proof of concept. Your `objItems` is "static" after the promise is completed.

Comment: Gotcha. Appreciate it. Is there anyway you could possibly interpret that into my code maybe edit it  in?

Comment: Would appreciate a response

Comment: @zgoforth are you asking for example where the data matches yours? Like {program:"p1", To: "a", Date: "8/5/2020",.....}? or how the code fits into a promise?

Comment: @zgoforth take a look now. The snippet uses `Promise.all` and matches your data structure

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219291/discussion-between-zgoforth-and-a123).

Comment: Check my recent edit, is there no way I could do something along the lines of that?

Comment: @zgoforth I don't think I can help you at this point. I think you have all the pieces you just have to decide how you want to group your data.

Comment: Ive explained how I want to group it the code you provided though just seems vague.